# Use custom order item metadata in ShipStation for WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, orders

I Got a WooCommerce store with the Shipstation for WooCommerce plugin installed. They provide a simple PHP function to send custom field data associated with an order to ShipStation. Here's the snippet:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipstation_export_custom_field_2', 'shipstation_custom_field_2' );
function shipstation_custom_field_2() {
    return '_meta_key'; // Replace this with the key of your custom field
}
```

This works great as long as the `_meta_key` you want to set is located in the `wp_postmeta` table. But the meta key is located in `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` table *(the related meta key is `_wc_checkout_add_on_value`)*.

Is there some way to get the ShipStation function above to look up `_wc_checkout_add_on_value` in the `wp_woodcommerce_order_itemmeta` table?

Or, as a workaround, is there a way to return a fixed text string instead of a meta key? I've tried everything I can think of but can't get it to work. Seems to want a meta key from the `wp_postmeta` table and nothing else will do.

Here's the logic I think might work here:

1. Check for a particular value in the `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta`
   table for each order
2. If the value is found, send a fixed text string for the "shipstation_custom_field_2" that gets send to ShipStation.

I can do the first part of this. It's the second part, sending a fixed value to SS, that I can't seem to get working. Maybe it's impossible with this function.

Any ideas or workarounds would be most welcome.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipstation_export_custom_field_2', 'shipstation_custom_field_2' );

function shipstation_custom_field_2() {
    //return '_meta_key'; // Replace this with the key of your custom field
    //return 'test';
    echo 'test';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding--I edited my question to try and explain better. The meta data I want to pass is a custom add-on field from the Woo checkout with a meta key called _wc_checkout_add_on_value in the wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta table. If that's not possible or practical, I can just check _wc_checkout_add_on_value for a particular value and if that value exists then send a fixed text string to ShipStation in the shipsation_custom_field_2 field. Hope that makes sense., Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: I have maybe a turn around in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**: What you can try to do when the order is just created, is to check order items for this custom order item metadata and add it as order metadata.

But if there are multiple items (at least 2) you have 2 choices:

- merge the data in a comma separated string before saving,
- set the data in an array before saving.

**So there are 2 cases:**

1). Set the data as a comma separated string *(for one or multiple items)*

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_created', 'save_order_item_meta_as_order_meta' );
function save_order_item_meta_as_order_meta( $order ) {
    $meta_data = array(); // Initializing

    // loop through order items
    foreach( $order->get_items(['line_item', 'shipping', 'fee', 'coupon', 'tax']) as $item ) {
        $meta_value = $item->get_meta('_wc_checkout_add_on_value'); // Get the metadata

        if ( ! empty($meta_value) ) {
            $meta_data[] = $meta_value;
        }
    }

    if ( empty($meta_data) ) return; // Exit if emptty

    // Save as a comma separated string of values
    $order->add_meta_data('_wc_checkout_add_on_values', implode(', ', $meta_data), true);
    $order->save();
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin).

You can change the separator `', '` as you like in the implode() function.

If there is only one order item, you will get the value just like in the order item.

---

2). Set the data as an **array of values** *(for one or multiple items)*

Simply replace in my function:

```php
    // Save as a comma separated string of values
    $order->add_meta_data('_wc_checkout_add_on_values', implode(', ', $meta_data), true);
```

with:

```php
    // Save as an array of values
    $order->add_meta_data('_wc_checkout_add_on_values', $meta_data, true);
```

---

To finish:

You will use your ShipStation filter hook as follows:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipstation_export_custom_field_2', 'shipstation_custom_field_2' );
function shipstation_custom_field_2() {
    return '_wc_checkout_add_on_values'; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million Loic. I'm placing test orders and I can see that it's adding a new row called _wc_checkout_add_on_values to the wp_postmeta table as intended but the value is always empty. When I look in the wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta table I can see there are values showing for _wc_checkout_add_on_value.

I've tried a bunch of different variations on your code but coming up short. I'm having trouble understanding how $meta_value could be empty since I'm seeing values in the _wc_checkout_add_on_values table for that key. Thank you again for your time.

Comment: @Megunticook I just made changes to my code extending order items to other types and checking that the metadata is not empty. But it should be better if you can check what item type of order item is it in `wp_woodcommerce_order_items` table (making the relation between tables via `order_item_id`).

Comment: Bingo! Give that man a cigar. Thank you so much. It was "fee" item type. Just tested and I see the value now. If I could I'd buy you a beer my friend. Take care.